# study of convergence of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

> I want to study the convergence of the integral $$\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (1+|\xi|^2)^{-s} d\xi,$$
>   where $s \in \mathbb{R}$.
>   More precisely, I want to prove that the integral converges if $s > \frac{n}{2}$.

I tried using polar coordinates $\xi= r \cos \theta$, with $r >0$ and $\theta \in ]0,2\pi[$.
Then we obtain 
$$
\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (1+r^2|\cos(\theta)|^2)^{-s} dr d\theta 
$$
but I have no idea to how to continue.

Comment: You're missing the Jacobian in your integral after the variable change.

Comment: Moreover, note that $\xi$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, so $\xi = r\cos\theta$ makes no sense.

Comment: can you show me the good formula please beacause i'm lost. i did not know that we can use the polar coordinate only in dimension 2

Comment: [Spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)

Comment: But I think that polar coordinates is not the best way to go.